# Date format is recognised as custom in excel and not as date, where the excel sheet is generated using ruby on rails framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel

I am using Axlsx gem in ruby-on-rails framework to generate a spreadsheet in .xlsx format, the spreadsheet gets generated but it detects the date field only in the Linux distros, in windows if I download the generated file, the date values are detected as general or custom

I have tried to solve the issue using RubyXL gem, but still wasn't able to solve it

I am expecting the excel application in windows to detect the date format in the generated spreadsheet.

Comment: Please share some code. I am using date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") and it works fine

Comment: p = Axlsx::Package.new
    p.workbook.add_worksheet(name: 'Sheet1') do |sheet|
        style = sheet.styles.add_style(format_code: "mm/dd/yyyy")

Comment: Can u share me ur code, of how u have formated ur code and how u generate the spreadsheet

Comment: I am not using this sheet.styles.add_style(format_code: "mm/dd/yyyy"). Just  date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") where I need to write date

Comment: ooh, the issue is my data is very very huge, so if I perform operations using Date class its going to have a huge overload on the server